# How to redirect users to a subdomain based on IP location?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, subdomain

I am using Node Express for my website and I would like to redirect users based on their current location, for example, if users in Singapore open `site.com`, then redirect them to the subdomain `sg.site.com` (this one is hosted on the same server as site.com). I am able to find user's IP address and location but how to redirect them to the proper subdomain?

Comment: Use switch case and use window.location = sg.site.com;

Comment: @UllasHunka he tries to find user specific data to then redirect him to his subdomain site.

Comment: @marpme That's what Ullas is suggesting yes

Comment: Well sorry misunderstood his requirement, Ullas is right with this frontend solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean from server-side Express code, with [`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect):

> **`res.redirect([status,] path)`**
>
> Redirects to the URL derived from the specified `path`, with specified `status`, a positive integer that corresponds to an [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) . If not specified, status defaults to “302 “Found”.
>
> ```
> res.redirect('/foo/bar');
> res.redirect('http://example.com');
> res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com');
> res.redirect('../login');
> ```

If you mean client-side, assign to the [`location` object](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.location.html).

> Replace the current document with the one at the given URL:
>
> ```
> function goMoz() {   
>    window.location = "http://www.mozilla.org";  
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
res.redirect('https://app.example.io');
```

Express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

---

It works basically like you would redirect users to an external page,but you can add your subdomain as well. Like this one:

```
function requestHandler(req, res) {
    res.redirect('https://sg.site.com');
}
```

Comment: What about the part with finding the location of the user?

Comment: @AhmedBajra "I am able to find user's IP address and location", he's already able to find them, but he was not sure how to redirect people.